# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in flutter while app is in background

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing the 'Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)' for app based notifications and getting the following error while trying to call `sendLocalNotification` function in `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` while app is in background.

```
 An error occurred in your background messaging handler: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

And below is the sample code,

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging().onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  void sendLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  }
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  var myAppState = _MyAppState();
  myAppState.sendLocalNotification(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you provided, the `_MyAppState` class is being created inside the `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` method. So, that means it does not have the context to use/access the Firebase instance.

Just create a MyApp instance using the `.createState()` function and then you can use that state to call the `sendLocalNotification()` method.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) 
 async {
     var myAppState = MyApp().createState();
     myAppState._MyAppState().sendLocalNotification(message);
}
```

Comment: Now able to call the function but not able to access `setState()` and `shared preferences` inside the `sendLocalNotification` function. can you please help on this?